# How to best store scallions?

Tags: storage-method, onions

They always get wilted in the crisper pretty quickly.  Is there a better way to store them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stilltasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17339) recommends that you wrap the scallions (or green onions) in plastic wrap, and that site also says they'll last 7-10 days that way.

I actually wrap them in a damp paper towel and then in plastic wrap. I keep this little packet in the crisper drawer. I've kept them about 2 weeks this way.

Either way, each time you open the packet you should check for damaged parts and discard them.

Answer (score 7):

I always stand them upright in a narrow glass, with a little water in the bottom. I the keep the glass either on the top shelf or the door of the refrigerator.

Comment: Do you cut the bunch in half so they would fit vertically?

Comment: If you're storing them for a long time, you'll want to change the water out at a minimum of once a week or it'll start to get a bit slimy.  I've held green onions for 3-4 weeks this way.  And regarding trimming them -- the door of the fridge generally has taller vertical space (set up for 2L soda bottles), so height isn't a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was born in 1931.  From when I was a little girl I remember scallions being stored standing upright in a glass of water.  We didn't even have a refrigerator then.  Now I keep them in the water in the fridge. Works better than the grocery's plastic bag in the crisper drawer.

Answer (score 4):

I love green onions! I will usually cut the onion to just the edge of the green part. I then store it in a glass of water. The green part gets cut into small chives and stored in a container with sealing lid in the freezer door, for soups and casseroles. I like to dip the the root stalks in ranch dressing. Yum!